# From Matlab/fmincon To SciPy/minimize

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, minimization, scipy-optimize

I'm trying to convert a minimization process from Matlab to Python/SciPy.

Below, the main Matlab script:

```
d = 0.5;
n = 7;
l = n * (n - 1) * d;

ko = ones(n,1) .* d.* n;
ki = ones(n,1) .* d.* n;
so = [7 5 3 1 3 0 1];
si = [4 5 5 0 0 2 4];

x0 = [ko / sqrt(l); ki / sqrt(l); 0.9 * ones(n,1); 0.9 * ones(n,1)];
lb = zeros(4*n,1);
ub = [ones(2*n,1)*Inf;ones(2*n,1)+0.1];
options = optimset('Display','off','Algorithm','interior-point','GradObj','off','DerivativeCheck','off','MaxFunEvals',10^5,'MaxIter',10^3,'TolX',10^(-32),'TolFun',10^(-32));

res = fmincon(@(x)obj_fun(x,ko,ki,so,si,n),x0,[],[],[],[],lb,ub,[],options);
```

And the objective function is defined as follows:

```
function G = obj_fun(m,ko,ki,so,si,n)

    xo = m(1:n);
    xi = m(n+1:2*n);
    yo = m(2*n+1:3*n);
    yi = m(3*n+1:4*n);

    g = 0;

    for i = 1:n
        g = g + (ko(i) * log(xo(i))) + (ki(i) * log(xi(i))) + (so(i) * log(yo(i))) + (si(i) * log(yi(i)));
    end

    f = 0;

    for i = 1:n
        for j = 1:n
            if i ~= j
                f = f + log(1 - yo(i) * yi(j)) - log(1 - (yo(i) * yi(j)) + (xo(i) * xi(j) * yo(i) * yi(j)));
            end
        end
    end

    g = -(g + f);

end
```

Everything runs smoothly in Matlab and the minimization process finishes in a few seconds, providing the following result:

```
res = [
   5018.1,  6131.5,   10276,    21353,   8579.3,    35118,    26854,
   7994.8,  7385.6,  8907.3,    35322,    35236,    13084,   7167.6,
   1.0882, 0.94876, 0.00619,   0.4943, 3.67e-06, 3.11e-11, 2.20e-09,
   0.5144, 0.36119, 0.27945, 1.06e-12, 5.97e-12, 1.59e-08, 9.07e-05
];
```

Here is my attempt to replicate this framework in Python, using SciPy optimization tools and, specifically, the `minimize` function:

```
def obj_fun(x, ko, ki, so, si, n):

    split = _np.split(x, 4)
    xo = split[0]
    xi = split[1]
    yo = split[2]
    yi = split[3]

    g = np.zeros(1)

    for i in range(n):
        g += (ko[i] * np.log(xo[i])) + (ki[i] * np.log(xi[i])) + (so[i] * np.log(yo[i])) + (si[i] * np.log(yi[i]))

    f = _np.zeros(1)

    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if i != j:
                f += np.log(1.0 - (yo[i] * yi[j])) - np.log(1.0 - (yo[i] * yi[j]) + (xo[i] * xi[j] * yo[i] * yi[j]))

    sol = -(g + f)
    jac = np.zeros(n * 4)

    return sol, jac

d = 0.5
n = 7
l = n * (n - 1) * d

ki = np.ones(n) * d * n
ko = np.ones(n) * d * n
si = np.array([[7, 5, 3, 1, 3, 0, 1]])
so = np.array([[4, 5, 5, 0, 0, 2, 4]])

x0 = np.concatenate((ko / np.sqrt(l), ki / np.sqrt(l), 0.9 * np.ones(n), 0.9 * np.ones(n)), axis=None)
bounds = [(0.0, None) if not np.isfinite(b) else (0.0, b) for b in np.repeat(_np.array([np.inf, 1.1]), n * 2)]

res = spo.minimize(lambda x: obj_fun(x, ko, ki, so, si, n), x0, method='trust-constr', jac=True, bounds=bounds)
```

As you may have noticed, I'm returning a null jacobian matrix from the objective function because I don't know the gradient. If I don't return it, the process fails taking forever to finish and flooding my console with the following messages:

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less if reduction_ratio < SUFFICIENT_REDUCTION_RATIO and \

RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater_equal if reduction_ratio >= LARGE_REDUCTION_RATIO:

RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater_equal elif reduction_ratio >= INTERMEDIARY_REDUCTION_RATIO:

RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less elif reduction_ratio < SUFFICIENT_REDUCTION_RATIO:

RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less_equal return (lb <= x).all() and (x <= ub).all()
```

Here is the solution suggested by the code above, which is nowhere close to what MATLAB found:

```
x: array([0.95283666, 0.95283666, 0.95283666, 0.95283666, 0.95283666,
   0.95283666, 0.95283666, 0.95283666, 0.95283666, 0.95283666,
   0.95283666, 0.95283666, 0.95283666, 0.95283666, 0.7914069 ,
   0.7914069 , 0.7914069 , 0.7914069 , 0.7914069 , 0.7914069 ,
   0.7914069 , 0.7914069 , 0.7914069 , 0.7914069 , 0.7914069 ,
   0.7914069 , 0.7914069 , 0.7914069 ])
```

I tried all the alternative bounded minimization algorithms available: `L-BFGS-B` and `SLSQP`. They fail in converging to a solution, and a lot of warnings are issued, probably concerning NaN or Inf values passed to log functions and divisions:

```
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log
...
```

Comment: It is highly recommended to provide exact gradients. If you cannot provide gradients, you should **not** use `jac=True`.

Comment: Let me update the question so I can better explain what happens when I use jac=False...

Comment: Ok, it's done! Post edited.

Comment: You should protect logs either by setting bounds or by changing `log(x)`  to `log(max(x,1e-6))`. NLP solvers I work with don't evaluate nonlinear functions when a variable is outside its bounds (I am not sure about scipy solvers in this respect).